# Referencing data in a struct using switch in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a switch statement in my code to decide between several cases.  Depending on the choice, I would like to load a specific dataset and use that dataset for the remainder of the program.  One of the challenges as well is that the arrays in my structs will be arbitrary lengths.  What I am trying to avoid is rewriting my main program multiple times for every case.  My data is included in my scenariodata.h file, and my program is in test.cpp.  Right now it doesn't compile, but if it works the way I want, it should show '10' in the console. Many thanks in advance.

#### test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "scenarioData.h"

int main(){
    int choice = 1;

    //initialize a blank struct with generic name 'sd'
    sd_fmt sd;

    switch((int) choice){
        //Make a decision of which data set to use
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Using data1\n";
            sd = data1;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Using data2\n";
            sd = data2;
            break;
    }

    //From here on do all my work with general variable name 'sd'
    std::cout << sd.speed[1];  //Should show 10 in the console

    return 0;
}
```

#### scenarioData.h

```
struct sd_fmt {
    double *speed;
};

struct sd_fmt {
    double speed[4] = {1,10,100,1000};
} data1;

struct sd_fmt{
    double speed[5] = {2,200,2000, 20,20000};
} data2;
```

Comment: You can't compile because you have three different `struct`s all with the same name (identifier). You could use inheritance here, but that's pretty abusive. I think you are better off with one `struct` and different ways it can be initialized. Rather than different arrays of speeds, consider a `std::vector` Different `vector` instances can have different sizes and they know their size.

Comment: You need to have two different structs with good names. You can then probably make a union of the two.

Comment: @KorelK It is a question about C++ if the code is intended to be C++ and compiled with a C++-compiler. It is not a matter of the language features used.

Comment: My biggest concern is that you can look at the code and have no idea what these "speed" structures are. If you just had a vector, you can look at its length and know you have that many speeds. The fact that it won't compile because you reuse the same name for different types is less important to me.

Comment: @KorelK, I can appreciate your comment, but I'm not experienced enough with C/C++ to know the difference.  Generally my programming experience has been in python.

Comment: First thing to know is there is no C/C++. Some folks even get offended when they see C/C++. Best to burn the extra few characters and go with "C and C++" when you mean both.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to cast an `int` variable to an `int` for the `switch`; it's kind of redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the fragment to a more modern style of C++.

The structure definitions were confused with the declaration of an instances of the struct. Instead of creating a structure containing a pointer, the std::vector is used.  Use of pointer should be avoid where possible.

The vector has multiple advantages including being variable sized.  The initialize of the vector is straightforward as well.  If a vector has a known size then the at() member can be used to access a particular element.

The switch statement makes a copy of the vector which is not ideal.  If the vector was very large then using a reference to the vector would be more efficient. For this small example, it is a non-issue.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using sd_fmt = std::vector<double>;

sd_fmt data1 = {1,10,100,1000};
sd_fmt data2 = {2,200,2000, 20,20000};

int main(){
    int choice = 1;

    //initialize a blank struct with generic name 'sd'
    sd_fmt sd;

    switch((int) choice){
        //Make a decision of which data set to use
        case 1:
        std::cout << "Using data1\n";
        sd = data1;
        break;
        case 2:
        std::cout << "Using data2\n";
        sd = data2;
        break;
    }

    //From here on do all my work with general variable name 'sd'
    std::cout << sd.at(1);  //Should show 10 in the console

    return 0;
}
```